# Signalr - Long message delay

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have developed a chat application using signalr and asp.net mvc. When a user sends a long message (100 - 200 characters), it will take some time to transfer. This happens from both the ends - client and server and when the application is running on the online server, but this won't happen when the application is running on a local server.

My question is how can we solve this delay problem in signalr so that messages can be sent frequently without delay?

Comment: How many clients are connected? Is your SignalR hub in a server farm and are you using a backplane? If so, which backplane implementation?

Comment: Only 1 client is connected and I'm not using backplane

Comment: Hmmm... You mentioned the application is on an "online server". Are you saying it is on the Cloud, such as Azure or a third-party hosting service? It almost sounds like a simple network delay.

Comment: Online server means the application is online and not saying about Cloud

Comment: Does this happen every time or every so often? Could the server be set to cold-start?

Comment: long message delay happens every time whenever a user transfer a message with 100-200 characters

Comment: The application is not on cloud

Comment: Have you tried opening PerfMon on the server to monitor the SignalR counters? [See "SignalR Performance"](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance#perfcounters) What version of SignalR are you working with?

Comment: No, tell me steps how to do this....